# Async/await jest test using firebase not ending

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, jestjs, firebase-authentication

I'm using jest to test my logIn function in my app. It uses google firebase's signInWithEmailAndPassword function, so the test needs to deal with asynchronous code. I followed the documentation here https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous, but when I run the test, it doesn't end.

Here is the function I'm testing:

```
export const logIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(userCredential => {
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log('user');
      console.log(user);
      return true;
      // ...
    })
    .catch(error => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode);
      console.log('Error message: ' + errorMessage);
      return false;
    });
};
```

It should return true if the user credentials are correct, and false otherwise.

Here is my test:

```
test('logIn should return true if user info is correct', async () => {
  let value = await logIn('noahmatwalker@gmail.com', 'password');
  expect(value).toBe(true);
});
```

The test doesn't appear to end, so I have to ctrl+c to stop it. The funny thing is the function works when used in my app normally.

Edit:

Alright, I have mocked the function using signInWithEmailAndPassword. This is the mock and test.

```
jest.mock('../src/functions/helperFunctions', () => ({
  logIn: async () => {
    console.log('hello');
    return true;
  },
}));

test('testing logIn function', async () => {
    console.log('hello');
    let value = await logIn('noahmatwalker@gmail', 'password');
    value = true;
    console.log('after await');
    expect(value).toBe(true);
  });
```

The hello console.logs are being displayed, but I'm still running into the same issue where the test won't end. The 'after await' log doesn't show, so for some reason logIn is not resolving.

Comment: The first thing is should not test against the actual service, mock it instead. You are not testing that Firebase works correctly, which you are doing by calling the real service. You want to test that your code works in the different cases (log in success, failure, other error), which a mock will allow your test to do.  You might be getting a prompt from the Firebase login as the test is running in Jest, different than your code.  Have you checked to console to see if your console.log() is writing anything?

Comment: Ok cool that makes since. I'm testing this easy sign in feature on my app, so I just need to it return true or false for now. And no, the test wouldn't resolve so I never saw the console logs when running the test. I do see them when the function is used in my regular app though.

Comment: If you are not seeing the console.log, then it looks like things are not running properly.  The signInWithEmailAndPassword() should have been called regardless, so that is what is not resolving.  Maybe there is something else in between?  You could change your logIn() to simply return false/true (resolve/reject) to ensure your code is coming back correctly. Then a simple mock would replace that where you spyOn and it resolves/rejects.

Comment: First question, if the test doesn't end wouldn't I not see any of the console logs what happened during that test? @StevenScott

Comment: Second, I mocked login() to return true and got rid of async/await. It "works" and I can use it to check screen transitions when a user signs. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: For #1, I would expect a console.log before the code not ending (an external call) would be displayed.  You might need console.log before your call to the actual external service signInWithEmailAndPassword(), before the return.  Otherwise, correct, nothing will show.

Comment: For #2, you should still have async/await in your code and tests.  The reason is the real function is asynchronous and you want to 'wait' for the external call in your test, even though it is mocked and returning right away.  Other tests for different functions might take a bit to run, and not awaiting the response, your test will fail since the calling code did not execute in time.

Comment: Alright I mocked the function, but I am still getting the same issue. I did add some logs before and after the async bit.

Comment: My guess is the mock, and the actual include, are using different paths, so you are not mocking the actual function in question.

Comment: You might even be able to simply replace your function with a simple fake object, something like:
 const logInFake = {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password): Promise.resolve(true);
 }

Comment: The console.log from my mock is showing up, so I'm assuming it's using the correct function.

Comment: Added a sample from one of my services in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I am doing in a test, where I am mocking my AdminCodesService and providing results for the different functions.  This is sample code from my NestJS application using Jest as the test suite.

AdminCodesService.spec.ts

```
...

let service: AdminCodesService;
afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockAdminCodesService = {
        provide: AdminCodesService,
        useFactory: () => ({
            GetAll: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([new AdminCodesResponseDTO(77, 'Test Admin Code'), new AdminCodesResponseDTO(88, 'Test Admin Code 2')]),
            GetOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(new AdminCodesResponseDTO(77, 'Test Admin Code')),
        }),
    };

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [mockAdminCodesService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AdminCodesService>(AdminCodesService);
});
    
it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
});

it('should return all AdminCodes', async () => {
    const Results$: Array<AdminCodesResponseDTO> = await AdminCodesServiceTestInstance.GetAll();
    expect(Results$.length).toBe(2);
    
    Results$.forEach((Result: AdminCodesResponseDTO) => {
        expect(Result.AdminCode).toBeDefined();
        expect(Result.Description).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The above snippet will never call the real service, but will mock the results.  From here, I can test my code behaves as it should, based on the returns.

This is different then the complete external file mock which you are using, but tries to do the same thing.  However, if you have a lot of methods in your main class, then it is not advisable to use my method here, as you need to mock all of those as well. This works for more simple mocks.